# Create scheduled task with powershell

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have this script to create a scheduled task in using PowerShell which works fine however I can't figure out how to "Set and expiry date", "Run with highest privileges" and "stop the task if its running longer then".

```
$taskName = "TestTask"
$user = "<....>"
$password = "<...>"
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "notepad.exe" 
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Weekly -AT "23:00" -DaysOfWeek 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday'
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet 
$inputObject = New-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -Settings $settings 
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -InputObject $inputObject -User $user -Password $password
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to specify the appropriate parameters on the New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet command e.g.

```
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet `
                -ExecutionTimeLimit ([TimeSpan]::FromHours(2)) `
                -DeleteExpiredTaskAfter ([TimeSpan]::FromDays(60) 
Register-ScheduledTask ... -Settings $settings -RunLevel Highest
```

Look at this help topic for more info on the [New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtasksettingsset?view=win10-ps) command.