# Delete the Script's source folder that it is running from

Tags: powershell, directory

As the title suggests, I'm trying to see if I can run a script from folder X that ultimately deletes folder X at the end.

Start with .zip file, extract to C:\Source (contains script and other folders)
Run script, it moves the other folders proper locations including the script.
Script deletes it self and then deletes folder X.

However it kicks back and error saying that it can't delete folder X because it is in use.

Am I crazy (most likely) or can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

No you're not crazy. This makes total sense, since your script is running in said folder. The only way it will successfully delete is if you end the script (Script not open anymore means the script file can now be deleted, and since the only thing halting the folder deletion was your script being open/in use, the folder itself should now delete without issue).

The only way around this in my opinion, aside from closing the script and deleting it and its folder manually, would be to have the scripts final actions be to schedule a run-once windows event to delete the folder in say 10 seconds (This message will self destruct in ten seconds!).
Luckily, StackOverflow has part of this solution answered for you, right here: [Create scheduled task with powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28918509/create-scheduled-task-with-powershell)